# Is it correct to say that a git rebase is equivalent to a git cherry-pick of certain commits from the other direction?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I'm trying to tighten up my understanding (and communication) of git commands.

Is it correct to say that

```
git checkout A
git rebase B
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick <all_commits_from_common_ancestor_of_<A>_and_<B>_to_<A>>
```

And if not, in what scenario do they diverge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git cherry pick vs rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835948/git-cherry-pick-vs-rebase)

Comment: I did read that question, but I couldn't absorb enough to confidently answer my question of translating one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *quite* correct.

There are several stumbling blocks here.  First, there may not be a common ancestor, or there might be more than one.  (This is pretty minor: that just means all commits get copied, or all common ancestors get omitted.)  Second, we might not check out the commit specified by *`B`* here.  Third, some commits can be omitted, and depending on the form of rebase, this can get a bit complicated.  Last, the copying happens in *detached HEAD* mode, and afterward, rebase yanks the branch name around (as if via `git checkout -B` or `git switch -C`, or `git branch -f` followed by `git checkout` or `git switch`).

The actual commits that are to be enumerated depend on the *`upstream`* argument to rebase, which can be specified this way:

```
git rebase --onto <target> <upstream>
```

or:

```
git rebase <upstream>
```

If the `--onto <target>` option is left out, the *`target`* is the same as the *`upstream`*.  This is the commit that gets checked out (in detached-HEAD mode).

[The rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) first suggests that commits to be enumerated are those in:

```
upstream..HEAD
```

(before the checkout step of course, as that moves `HEAD`).  This is not quite true, so the current documentation immediately corrects itself a bit:

> This is the same set of commits that would be shown by `git log <upstream>..HEAD`; or by `git log 'fork_point'..HEAD`, if `--fork-point` is active (see the description on `--fork-point` below); or by `git log HEAD`, if the `--root` option is specified.

Just a bit later, it adds this:

> Note that any commits in HEAD which introduce the same textual changes as a commit in HEAD..<upstream> are omitted (i.e., a patch already accepted upstream with a different commit message or timestamp will be skipped).

It's not until much later that it mentions that *merge commits* are omitted entirely, unless you use the (now deprecated) `-p` option or the (new in Git 2.18) `-r` option.

What's really going on here, though, is that Git is using the three-dot syntax for `git rev-list`, with the `--left-right` mode.<sup>1</sup>  The base three-dot syntax:

```
git rev-list upstream...HEAD
```

enumerates all commits that are reachable from *either* commit, but *not* reachable from *both* commits.  In graph theoretical terms, this is the *symmetric difference*.  It's described briefly in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  This forces the revision-walking code to examine commits reachable from `HEAD` but not *`upstream`* *and* commits reachable from *`upstream`* but not `HEAD`.  While it's doing that, Git performs a [`git patch-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) on each commit.  This lets `git rebase` locate commits that are "the same" (in terms of what they change), and thus omit them if they've already been cherry-picked to the upstream branch.

In particular, then, suppose you have:

```
...--o--*--D--E--B'--F   <-- their-branch
         \
          A--B--C   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

and you run `git rebase their-branch` to copy your three `A-B-C` commits to come after `F`.  The rebase code will compute the patch-IDs from `A`, `B`, and `C`, and also the patch-IDs from `D`, `E`, `B'`, and `F`.  Given that commit `B'` is a copy of your commit `B`, it probably<sup>2</sup> has the same patch-ID.  So Git will *omit* `B` from the list of commits to copy.

The `--fork-point` mode is described somewhat obliquely, but you should first note that `--fork-point` is the default option in some cases, and `--no-fork-point` is the default option in others.  The way fork-point mode works is to use your reflogs.  See [Git rebase - commit select in fork-point mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486141/1256452) for more about this.

There is a relatively new `--keep-base` option that really does a merge base computation.  You can invoke it directly with the three-dot syntax, or use the `--keep-base` option to turn it on.

Finally, the omission of merge commits (except with `-r`, or the `-p` option that you should avoid) occurs because Git literally *can't* copy a merge.  The omission of merges is basically the same as using the `--no-merges` option when running `git rev-list`.  When you use the `-r` option, Git will enumerate the merges and make note of them, and will use the fancier new interactive scripting mode to *re-perform* the merges.  That is, given a graph fragment like this:

```
...--o--*-------F   <-- their-branch
         \
          \   B
           \ / \
            A   D--E   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
             \ /
              C
```

a `git rebase -r` will produce:

```
                      B'
                     / \
                    A'  G--E'   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
                   / \ /
                  /   C'
                 /
...--o--*-------F   <-- their-branch
         \
          \   B
           \ / \
            A   D--E   [abandoned]
             \ /
              C
```

where new merge commit `G` is produced by literally running `git merge` on commits `B'` and `C'`.  If you made `D` as an [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452) using `git merge --no-commit`, the evilness will be lost during this re-merging.  The remaining commits, marked with the prime suffix (`A'` etc), are done by copying, using the underlying cherry-pick machinery.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>In the old days, `git rebase` was several shell scripts, and one of them really did run `git rev-list` like this, although it used `--right-only --cherry-pick`, as I recall.  It's been rewritten in C since then and now it's ... more complicated. :-)

<sup>2</sup>Whether it has the same patch-ID depends on whether someone had to modify it while copying it.  See [the `git patch-id` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) for details.

<sup>3</sup>In older versions of Git, the *default* is actually to use `git format-patch` and `git am`, or the internal equivalent.  This is physically unable to copy merges either, and misses some rename cases that cherry-pick detects.  During the addition of the new `-r` option, everything was set up to switch the default to use cherry-pick, and fairly recently (2.25ish?), that became the new default.

Comment: Hey, thanks for such an in-depth answer. There are some concepts here I'll have to review when I'm more versed in git. Not at all wanting to oversimplify your answer, but echoing things back to check my understanding. I've categorized the differences between the 2 methods I presented, into 3 classes. (1) _Preconditions and unexpected states_, _e.g._ there may not be a common ancestor, or a checkout may fail. Makes sense; but I take it these aren't typical of "basic," happy path scenarios.

Comment: (2) _How it gets there._ I see that the 2 approaches take different steps to get to the "end." For a beginner just wanting to "get there," there might not be any difference, unless there are conflicts. (3) _Options._ I meant only to ask about the most basic use, but I see that given advanced options the two methods can diverge as well.

Comment: Yes, particularly weird errors like checkout failure (part 1) are uncommon. The first common glitch that catches people is that, when doing a rebase with a merge in it, they don't realize how many commits will get copied (both sides of the merge!) and that the merge gets removed with both "legs" flattened out, but your formulation covers most of that—just not the "drop merges" case. A much rarer glitch occurs with the fork-point and patch-ID tricks: in particular you can "lose" a commit that you expected to get copied, this way. These are all part of part-2, the how-it-gets-there.